# Flutter log colors not changing when trying to log with different colors

Tags: flutter, logging, colors, console, ansi-escape

I am trying to log a colored log in the console but i am just getting a square box what might be the issue

Below is my Log

```
log('\x1B[31m$message\x1B[0m');
```

Below is how i am getting the log

```
[31m"HelloWorld"][0m
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the `log` coming from `dart:developer`? For me it is working with exactly the same syntax as yours.

Comment: @PeterKoltai yeah might it be because i am using android studio

Comment: I don't use Android Studio, with VSCode it works this way for me.